# jQuery fadeIn onscroll event not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a fixed-position header div that I want to fadeIn (by jQuery) when the page is scrolled down 100px.

The jquery I am using is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").scroll(function(){
    if ($("body").scrollTop() > 100) {
            $(".header").fadeIn();
                }
            else {
                $(".header").fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
```

The full code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxj0ynuk/

I have no idea why this doesn't work. I am not particularly confident with jQuery, so I am at a loss as to what has gone wrong.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use window.scroll or document.scroll function and use doument or 'body' height for fadeIn header [Document.scroll and body height fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxj0ynuk/4/)

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
   $(".header").fadeIn();
  }
 else {
  $(".header").fadeOut();
 }
});
```

```css
div.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

p {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<div class='header'>Header
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis cursus nisi sit amet suscipit. Etiam semper risus ac vulputate tincidunt. Duis sed neque sit amet lacus posuere egestas nec scelerisque nulla. Nam purus nunc, lobortis vel mauris
    sed, convallis imperdiet enim. Praesent nec erat ullamcorper, gravida turpis eu, mattis velit. Nulla porta pulvinar dolor quis scelerisque. Nullam at est at justo porttitor volutpat. Proin facilisis erat suscipit blandit porttitor. Maecenas egestas
    enim orci, ut egestas enim consequat a. Sed vehicula magna lorem, sed convallis erat porta non. Aenean quis consectetur nibh. Fusce nisl nulla, suscipit non vulputate eget, pellentesque et ligula. Curabitur sollicitudin urna ut sem euismod suscipit.
    Suspendisse eget lacus ut nisl luctus molestie. Vivamus convallis magna a dui ullamcorper, sed sagittis arcu volutpat. Suspendisse hendrerit erat sit amet rhoncus convallis. Praesent quis suscipit velit. Suspendisse quis porta eros, non pulvinar eros.
    Nam pellentesque pharetra dui, in interdum neque faucibus sit amet. Praesent quis orci nec neque posuere viverra. Integer volutpat sem id lectus congue, id vestibulum enim congue. Cras ultricies nunc justo, faucibus aliquam erat lobortis eu. Nullam
    mollis volutpat faucibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus eu lectus et quam tristique mollis in eu dolor. Aliquam volutpat scelerisque diam porta rutrum. Phasellus sed est tincidunt, pretium mauris non, bibendum nibh. Pellentesque accumsan
    lacinia ultricies. Aenean et dolor ut quam dictum dapibus quis sit amet nisi. Praesent enim tellus, scelerisque et varius eu, porta vel ex. Vestibulum vel massa
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you haven't added jQuery to your fiddle.

Assuming that you are loading jQuery on your page, you should be detecting scroll on `window` not body:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $(".header").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(".header").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
div.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}

p {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='header'>
  </div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla convallis cursus nisi sit amet suscipit. Etiam semper risus ac vulputate tincidunt. Duis sed neque sit amet lacus posuere egestas nec scelerisque nulla. Nam purus nunc, lobortis vel mauris
    sed, convallis imperdiet enim. Praesent nec erat ullamcorper, gravida turpis eu, mattis velit. Nulla porta pulvinar dolor quis scelerisque. Nullam at est at justo porttitor volutpat. Proin facilisis erat suscipit blandit porttitor. Maecenas egestas
    enim orci, ut egestas enim consequat a. Sed vehicula magna lorem, sed convallis erat porta non. Aenean quis consectetur nibh. Fusce nisl nulla, suscipit non vulputate eget, pellentesque et ligula. Curabitur sollicitudin urna ut sem euismod suscipit.
    Suspendisse eget lacus ut nisl luctus molestie. Vivamus convallis magna a dui ullamcorper, sed sagittis arcu volutpat. Suspendisse hendrerit erat sit amet rhoncus convallis. Praesent quis suscipit velit. Suspendisse quis porta eros, non pulvinar eros.
    Nam pellentesque pharetra dui, in interdum neque faucibus sit amet. Praesent quis orci nec neque posuere viverra. Integer volutpat sem id lectus congue, id vestibulum enim congue. Cras ultricies nunc justo, faucibus aliquam erat lobortis eu. Nullam
    mollis volutpat faucibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus eu lectus et quam tristique mollis in eu dolor. Aliquam volutpat scelerisque diam porta rutrum. Phasellus sed est tincidunt, pretium mauris non, bibendum nibh. Pellentesque accumsan
    lacinia ultricies. Aenean et dolor ut quam dictum dapibus quis sit amet nisi. Praesent enim tellus, scelerisque et varius eu, porta vel ex. Vestibulum vel massa
  </p>
```